# Can not set ASP.Net Gridview Template Column width to 0

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview

In a asp.net grid view I have add a TemplateColumn and I need to set its width to 0, Even if I set it in HTML code or code behind when it displayed it in browser it has a width. How to solve this?

***HTML***

```
<asp:TemplateField Visible="False" ControlStyle-Width="0">
            <HeaderStyle BorderWidth="0" Width="0"></HeaderStyle>
            <ItemStyle BorderWidth="0" Width="0"></ItemStyle>
            <FooterStyle BorderWidth="0" Width="0"></FooterStyle>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <itemstyle width="0" />
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="ExpandedContent" Visible="false" runat="server"></td> </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="label" colspan="2" align="left">
                    Test</asp:PlaceHolder>
                </td> </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterStyle BorderWidth="0px" Width="0px" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

***Output HTML***

[image: output]

***Output***

[image]

Comment: y dont you make it visible = false.......is there any reson ?

Comment: @Pranay Yes, Can't set it visibility to false because i'm doing something tricky (according to this tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Drill_down_Datagrid.aspx). Need to set its width to 0 but its content is displayed somewhere else in the gridview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found `TemplateColumn` `HeaderText` is automatically set to four spaces (automatically generated), setting the `HeaderText` to one space from UI fixed the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Set the font size of the data within the column to 0, hope this works.. thanks

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="CommID" Visible="true" ItemStyle-ForeColor="White"  
          HeaderText="" ItemStyle-Width="0px" ControlStyle-Width="0px" ItemStyle-Font-Size="0" >
```

Answer (score 0):

My advise is that you make the column invisible (set `Visible="false"`) and you define the property that you are binding on that column as one of the DataKeyNames on your grid; that way, you'll be able to retrieve it whenever you want.

for example:

```
<asp:gridview DataKeyNames="PropertyYouNeed,ID,SomethingElse" ... />
```

Then when you post back, you can get the data from the [GridView.DataKeys property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeys.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

below solution worked for me -
1. create below css

```
<style>
    .hidden { display: none;}
</style>
```

2. Modify your TemplateField as below

   < asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
       < HeaderStyle CssClass="hidden" Width="0px" />
       < ItemStyle CssClass="hidden" Width="0px" />
   < ItemTemplate> 
   < asp:HiddenField ID="IDVal" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("UserID") %>' />
   < /ItemTemplate>
   < /asp:TemplateField>

Hope this helps. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i tried with `ItemStyle-Width="0px" ControlStyle-Width="0px"` but it showing small column. then i try with `Visible="false"` then the column is not visible but the problem is when we try to get cell text in code behind, it shows "".

my solution:

set     `GridView1.Columns(2).Visible = False`

if you want to read data from that column then

```
 GridView1.Columns(2).Visible = True

 If GridView1.Rows(1).Cells(2).Text ="abc" Then
        'do somthing......

 GridView1.Columns(2).Visible = False
```